# What problem should appear when "spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled" is false?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

Since `Spring Framework` **6** exists available the [ProblemDetail](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/ProblemDetail.java) class.

Through some tutorials I wrote the following code:

```
//Ignore the two latest Parameters
@ExceptionHandler({CienciaNotFoundException.class})
ProblemDetail handlerMappingFor404(Exception ex, WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest req) {
    ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    problemDetail.setTitle("Resource requested does not exist");
    problemDetail.setDetail(ex.getMessage());
    problemDetail.setProperty("dateTime", DateTimeUtils.currentDateTime());
    return problemDetail;
}
```

And through `curl`, for the next command:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias/777 \
     -v -H "Accept: application/json" | jq .
```

is confirmed that it returns:

```
{
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Resource requested does not exist",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "No existe Ciencia con 'id' 777",
  "instance": "/ciencias/uri/v1/ciencias/777",
  "dateTime": "2023-07-23 21:21:49"
}
```

The output works as expected

The reason of this: the app is running through `Spring Boot` **3.1.1** and that output appears *even* when the [spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled) is declared *explicitly* with `false`, its default value.

**Question**

- What **problem** should appear when `spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled` is *false*?

Answer (score 0):

**Auto-configure ProblemDetails**

ProblemDetails can be auto-configured in Spring MVC to produce custom error messages with the application/problem+json media type.

This support can be enabled by setting the property spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled to true.

This means that enabling this (even without a ControllerAdvice or ExceptionHandlers configured) the response will be RFC 7807 compliant.

[More details](https://dev.to/noelopez/spring-rest-exception-handling-problem-details-2hkj)